# How to remove noise in inverter

Tags: inverter

1000w sine wave inverter

[image]

I downloaded the above schematic from the web, I constructed it and its functioning OK.

My problem is that this inverter causes distortion in my sound systems even with the tank circuit connected in the secondary winding of the inverter transformer.

I observed keenly and found that this noise is generated in the output side of the inverter.

What can I do to get rid of this noise?

Am using the 1000w inverter on a  2×12v/200AH power banks.

Comment: what sort of noise?

Comment: @JonRB thank you sir for your time,the noise produced is audible ,one can still hear it while listening to music.

Comment: So when you said observed, there is no scopeshot

Comment: @JonRB sir,to be frunk this is my first project and I have never used a scope before,won't I get assistance without providing scope shots?

Comment: no one has implied you won't get assistance. Noise by definition is unwanted signals. What you class as noise I might not class as noise. Likewise characteristics of the noise help hone in on the root cause or an optimum solution. Right now what has been stated is equivalent of "something is not right" and that really isn't anything to work with

Comment: You say you got this design from the web - did they give guidelines on PCB layout and potential EMI with other systems? Was the design assured to be suitable with sensitive analogue audio systems or was it just some half-baked circuit idea that kind of works but has no guarantees other than it might work? What are your expectations when looking for inverter circuits? Will it power your fridge - that would be about as much as I would expect from some throw-away circuit on the internet.

Comment: First off, that won't produce a sine wave.  The driver is just switching the polarity of the battety current through the transformer.  The driving signal is a square wave.  You are most likely hearing the edges of the square wave.  I don't think you can fix that easily.  Probably easier to build a better inverter than to try to fix this one.

Comment: @Andyaka you are right,I really expected it to run a fridge ,the guidelines were that if I want to get more watts,I should add the FETs in parallel but am yet to do that. The distortion made me halt for a while,I was afraid could destroy my refrigerator

Comment: @JRE true sir,how and where can I get the best schematics for a pure sine wave inverter?

Comment: Ok.  That's two very different uses.  It may be "clean" enough (close enough to being a sine wave) to be OK for the fridge, and still be too "noisy" to use with your amplifier.

Comment: @JonRB OK sir,I have tried to add some loads and the noise seem to be fading away,

Comment: @JRE true,because when I connect a TV set alone  the noise isn't felt,when I add an amplifier, no noise,but when I remove the TV set,you can't stand the noise produced by amplifier. To ruduce the noise am forced to put on a very loud music which is unbearable at night

Comment: Uh.  Wait.  Is the noise coming out of your speakers or the inverter?

Comment: @JRE the speakers

Comment: And no fuses are used.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf with the schematic,they had not provided but after designing it ,I used circuit breakers 30A  the d.c side 6A the output side

Comment: No individual gate resistors - recepie for disaster. But you are out of luck anyway without an oscilloscope. You can’t expect to develop power electronics without one.

Comment: @winny I made some improvements to the schematic while designing it and for the gates,I connected a 100 ohm resistor to each gate. About the scope,will get one soon but meanwhile,I can't just sit back n wait for the scope,am trying to apply whatever I have

Comment: Is it conducted or radiated noise?  Does it sound like fast tick or hum? Is Earth ground used?  Does coupling  earth ground reduce noise to battery -ve or Audio ground?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist sir,its a conducted noise and is so humming,the system is earthed and decoupling ground also available. No noise is produced at the battery side,but only at the output side and goes directly to the speakers

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are hearing a 50-60Hz noise as the output of the transfo is not properly filtered.

You need to add quite a bit of capacitor between the bank 1 and 2 to GND, they use battery but battery doesn't have fast transiant response.

If this doesn't solve it, you can add a [capacitance multiplier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wopmEyZKnYo) circuit between the transfo and the banks.

Comment: Quite helpful, I have added two 2.2uf capacitors to the gates of both banks and the noise seems reduced but not completely, I have constructed the capacitance multiplier circuit but am unable to connect it to the system between banks and transformer, any help?

Comment: Did the power MOSFETS get hotter, with the 2.2uF on their gates?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf they started warming up,but they didn't get hot. I improvised an auto fan using an NTC heat sensor in case of an up normal heating.